# How do i run junit test cases automatically in jenkins, upon a git push?

Tags: git, jenkins, junit

I'm using junit, jenkins and git. I want to see junit test case reports in jenkins on git push.how could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the "Build Triggers" to "Poll SCM"